# Tomcat - garbage collections on dynamically loaded classes

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collection

I'm a researcher in programming languages and I'm using dynamically created/loaded classes
to implement multi-stage metaprogramming.

I'm thinking about using a tomcat server to expose my works, so I will write a Servlet that create
java classes and loads them (tons of them).

To properly garbage collect such created classes the corresponding class loader must be garbage collected.
Is this my responsibility as a Servlet writer or the responsibility of the tomcat framework?
If is not a responsability of tomcat framework, is this an open security issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Wait, how would it be a security issue?

Comment: The trick is freeing everything.  Just because you null some pointers does not "save" you if you have other classes that reference the to-be-collected classes.  In particular, this means that you must always use a "factory" class that resolves to the may-be-collected class using ClassLoader.loadClass or its kin followed by Class.newInstance, vs just doing a `new MayBeCollected()` call.  And classes that use references to objects of your "problem" class must use superclass or interface references, not the actual class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat unreferences the web application classloader and the objects it created from it (servlets, filters, listener, …) upon undeployment of the application. This should make the web application classloader, all its classes and objects eligible for garbage collection (unless you have a classloader leak).

There are two possibilities that come to my mind that you could count as a security issue. First if you have a classloader leak one web application might access classes from another web application that runs inside the same Tomcat instance. Second if you allow users to create classes through your web application that's obviously going to be an issue.

Comment: Ok, I expected something like that. Can I programmatically control the undeployment-redeployement of the applications? like having the application redeployed from scratch every time it received a request?

Comment: That does not sound like a good way to use Tomcat. You can create a class loader for every request. Just make sure you unreference it, all its classses and their objects after the request and it becomes eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: That assumes your classloaders aren't "heavyweight" (use OS resources).

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you to free the ClassLoaders. Tomcat is a servlet engine, it won't meddle with your classloading or unloading. Still unclear on how it would be a security issue though.